# Check if key value is empty

Tags: php, arrays

How can i check if the value of the key is empty without specify the exactly key name?

this code is not working as expected. For example, the value for key `3-3-divisa` is empty but not filtered by empty function

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value[0]) && !empty($value[1])) {
        var_dump($value[0]);
        var_dump($value[1]);
    }
}
```

Output

```
array (size=1)
  '3-1-serie_quant' => string 'test' (length=5)
array (size=1)
  '3-1-divisa' => string 'test' (length=5)
array (size=1)
  '3-2-serie_quant' => string '' (length=5)
array (size=1)
  '3-2-divisa' => string '' (length=5)
array (size=1)
  '3-3-serie_quant' => string '' (length=5)
array (size=1)
  '3-3-divisa' => string '' (length=5)
array (size=1)
```

the expected output:

```
array (size=1)
  '3-1-serie_quant' => string 'test' (length=5)
array (size=1)
  '3-1-divisa' => string 'test' (length=5)
```

$data Array:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '3-1-serie_quant' => string 'test' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          '3-1-divisa' => string 'test' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '3-2-serie_quant' => string '' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          '3-2-divisa' => string '' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '3-3-serie_quant' => string '' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          '3-3-divisa' => string '' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '3-4-serie_quant' => string '' (length=0)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          '3-4-divisa' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: Of what type are `$value[0]` and `[1]`?

Comment: How your $data array looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) for that:

```
$data = array_filter($data, function($x)
{
   return array_filter($x, function($y)
   {
      return array_filter($y) == $y;
   }) == $x;
});
```

Comment: apparently this will output the exactly initial $data array. So is not working (empty values still present).

Comment: I've noticed structure after your edit. Fixed now (for common case, not just 2 values). In the [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/9MLoP)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like $value[0] and $value[1] are arrays, so try the following:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
   $field0 = reset($value[0]);
   if (!empty($field0)) {
       var_dump($value[0]);
   }
   $field1 = reset($value[1]);
   if (!empty($field1)) {
       var_dump($value[1]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value[0]) && !empty($value[1]) && strlen($value[0]) && strlen($value[1])) {
        var_dump($value[0]);
        var_dump($value[1]);
    }
}
```

https://www.php.net/empty

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP documentation about the [empty](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function:

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error.

Then `$value[0]` won't work correctly neither if you are using a version less than 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$value`s are arrays with `size = 1`:

```
array (size=1)
  '3-3-divisa' => string '' (length=5)
```

Also, the **one** key is not `0`. So `$value[0]` and `$value[1]` don't exist inside your array.

Try, if you're working with PHP 5.4+:

```
if(!empty(array_values($values)[0])
```